# How electric devices can sustain at such a huge voltages?

Tags: voltage

This is a common experience.When we buy any electricity run device ,it is given with it's specifications like it's operating voltage,current ranges. Also,normally power supply is 240 V , 50 Hz. 
But when we turn ON the switch, the electric devices have to face very high voltage level for initial microsecond  or millisecond time interval.

Please consider the below equations.

**current=dq/dt**  ( where q= electric charge)
and **voltage =current *resistance**.

So for extremely small time interval,the voltage is very high. So, I think that it is higher than operating voltage range of the device.

So my question is  how any device (for example light bulb) can sustain at such  a high voltage ?
can anybody explain with the help of mathematics and voltage equation,what happens for that extremely small interval of time?

Comment: Your question, especially the part about lightning doesn't make any sense.  There is a world of difference between a lightning strike and flicking on a light switch.  Your lightbulbs are designed to operate from one voltage, so they do.  You may as well ask why explosions in the combustion chambers of your car don't blow it up.

Comment: Your household power has the same voltage as lightning? Please make sure to never invite me for a cup of tea...

Comment: @PlasmaHH SORRY sir but i removed this line from the question ;-)

Comment: @RDrast SORRY sir but i removed this line from the question

Comment: q does NOT change instantaneously, so I = dq/dt does NOT imply that there will be a spike in voltage.

Comment: @ScottSeidman but the voltage will also not be linear or constant one for that extremely small interval of time. It will be like a ramp with very high slope

Comment: No, Votage will be a step function (or the step gating of an AC signal), the ramp of charge vs time will have the slope of CURRENT, and I=V/R

Comment: Different story when talking about driving inductive loads, but that's not what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. A high inrush current does not mean there's a high voltage. In electronic circuits, inrush current is caused by capacitors charging up. In a light bulb, the filament's resistance is lower when the bulb is cool, which allows more current at startup. The input voltage from the AC power line stays at 240 VAC.

EDIT: Here's an example circuit. I'm using DC to make it simple, but the same concepts apply to AC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fggSE5m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the voltage is first connected, the capacitor acts like a short circuit. This means the current is:

$$I_{in} = \frac {240\ \mathrm V} {0.1\ \Omega} = 2400\ \mathrm A$$

That's very large! But after the capacitor charges up to 240 V, it acts like an open circuit. Then the current is:

$$I_{in} = \frac {240\ \mathrm V} {0.1\ \Omega + 1000\ \Omega} \approx 0.240\ \mathrm A$$

That's much smaller! But the input voltage never changed. Ohm's Law (voltage = current * resistance) only works for resistors. There are other kinds of devices that don't obey Ohm's Law.

Here's a light bulb example. According to Wikipedia, the resistance of a 100 W, 120 V bulb when the bulb is cold is about 9.5 ohms. When the bulb is hot, the resistance is about 144 ohms. So when you first flip the switch, the current is:

$$I = \frac V {R_{cold}} = \frac {120\ \mathrm V}{9.5\ \Omega} \approx 12.6\ \mathrm A$$

After a tenth of a second, the current is:

$$I = \frac V {R_{hot}} = \frac {120\ \mathrm V}{144\ \Omega} \approx 0.83\ \mathrm A$$

(I'm leaving out some differences between AC and DC circuits, but this should give you the right idea.)

Comment: sir ,then why the same bulb fuses out if we perform switch ON and OFF 4 to 5 times within no time?

Comment: @pandu: because they are crap

Comment: @Adam Haun sir ,can u explain what u said above help of mathematics and voltage equation for that extremely small interval of time?

Comment: @pandu Light bulbs usually fail because of thermal stress. If new light bulbs burn out when you flip the switch, then the bulbs are probably bad. I'll update my answer with some math.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no extreme voltage across something like a lightbulb when first turned on.

While reading your first paragraph, I thought you were referring to the large electric field created in the mechanical switch as the contact just start to separate when opening, or are almost touching when closing.

This is a real issue with mechanical switches, and is probably the primary reason they eventually fail.  The arc will damage the contacts a little bit each time.  They are made from materials that are good at withstanding this, but eventually the wear and pitting will keep the switch from working within spec.  This is why switches and relays have a lifetime number of cycles rating.

Comment: sir ,normally power supply is 240 V ,50Hz .But  When we turned On the switch ,for a small interval the voltage is much higher than 240 V.

Comment: @pandu: what makes you think that this is so? where should that voltage come from? and how much is "much higher"?

Comment: @pandu: No, it's not.

Comment: @pandu: Not, that isn't right. Current, not voltage, is the rate of charge flow per unit time.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I=dq/dt , AND V=I *R .so for extremely small interval,the voltage is very high.

Comment: For a light bulb, the instant it is turned on, it appears as a very low resistance. This means it draws a lot of current briefly. As the filament heats up, its resistance increases, and so the current drops. At no time, for a light bulb, should it be seeing a very large voltage induced from itself or the mains.

Comment: There is also a fair chance that you are switching the bulb on at much less than full line voltage.  If you timed it right, you can even switch it on at 0 volts, but never will it see more than the line voltage.

Comment: why still down voted?

Comment: @pandu: I don't know since I didn't downvote your question.